# Sorting the dataframe based on the count of one column and plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, matplotlib

I have two columns in my data frame:

```
winner    opening_shortname
0      White         Slav Defense
1      Black  Nimzowitsch Defense
2      White     King's Pawn Game
3      White    Queen's Pawn Game
4      White     Philidor Defense
...      ...                  ...
20053  White        Dutch Defense
20054  Black         Queen's Pawn
20055  White    Queen's Pawn Game
20056  White         Pirc Defense
20057  Black    Queen's Pawn Game
```

I want to create the plot below, the top 10 opening and its winner colour proportion (%).

[image]

Comment: is the winner column correct? that looks like an index, is that the intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
topk = 10
z = df.groupby(['opening_shortname', 'winner']).size().unstack()
ax = z.loc[z.sum(1).sort_values().tail(topk).index].plot.barh(color=['black', 'white'], edgecolor='black')
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
```

This sorts by prevalence of opening *and* limits to the top `k` (e.g. 10 in the OP's question).  The "proportion (%)" mention in the question is ambiguous: the plot provided clearly shows decreasing totals from the top opening to the next ones, and the horizontal axis is removed.

Anyway, on the sample data you provided:

[image]

Comment: In that way the dataframe is not sorted

Comment: simple enough to fix. Also, I don't buy the "proportion (%)" requirement, see edits.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is name `df`, you can `groupby`+`count`+`unstack`. Then sort on the sum and take the top 10 to plot:

```
df2 = (df.assign(count=1)
         .groupby(['winner', 'opening_shortname'])
         .count()
         .unstack(level=0)
         .droplevel(0, axis=1)
      )

# plot part
idx = df2.sum(axis=1).sort_values().head(10).index
(df2.div(df2.sum(axis=1), axis=0) # calculate the proportion
    .fillna(0)
    .loc[idx, ['White', 'Black']]
    .plot.barh(color=['w', 'k'], edgecolor='k')
)
```

output:
[image: horizontal bars]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should re-shape your dataframe through:

```
df = df.groupby(by = ['opening_shortname', 'winner']).size().reset_index().rename(columns = {'opening_shortname': 'opening_shortname', 'winner': 'winner', 0: 'count'}).sort_values(['count', 'opening_shortname', 'winner'], ascending = False, ignore_index = True)
```

So you will get a dataframe like (fake data):

```
      opening_shortname winner  count
0     Queen's Pawn Game  White    141
1     Queen's Pawn Game  Black    132
2          Queen's Pawn  White     57
3          Queen's Pawn  Black     57
4      King's Pawn Game  Black     57
5         Dutch Defense  Black     53
6      Sicilian Defense  White     51
7      Sicilian Defense  Black     50
8   Nimzowitsch Defense  White     46
9   Nimzowitsch Defense  Black     45
10     Philidor Defense  Black     44
11         Slav Defense  White     43
12         Pirc Defense  White     42
13         Slav Defense  Black     39
14         Pirc Defense  Black     38
15     King's Pawn Game  White     38
16        Dutch Defense  White     36
17     Philidor Defense  White     31
```

Then you can plot your data, for example using [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
sns.barplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'count', y = 'opening_shortname', hue = 'winner', palette = ['white', 'black'], edgecolor = 'black')
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')

df = df.groupby(by = ['opening_shortname', 'winner']).size().reset_index().rename(columns = {'opening_shortname': 'opening_shortname', 'winner': 'winner', 0: 'count'}).sort_values(['count', 'opening_shortname', 'winner'], ascending = False, ignore_index = True)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.barplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'count', y = 'opening_shortname', hue = 'winner', palette = ['white', 'black'], edgecolor = 'black')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If, in place of count, you want to plot the relative proportion, then you can add one line to the above code:

```
df['count'] = df['count']/df.groupby('opening_shortname')['count'].transform('sum')
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')

df = df.groupby(by = ['opening_shortname', 'winner']).size().reset_index().rename(columns = {'opening_shortname': 'opening_shortname', 'winner': 'winner', 0: 'count'}).sort_values(['count', 'opening_shortname', 'winner'], ascending = False, ignore_index = True)
df['count'] = df['count']/df.groupby('opening_shortname')['count'].transform('sum')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.barplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'count', y = 'opening_shortname', hue = 'winner', palette = ['white', 'black'], edgecolor = 'black')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I realized both you and I forgot the requirement to get the proportion, not counts ;)

Comment: Thank you, answer updated accordingly :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not selecting the top 10.